# Doubling each item in a list

Tags: python, list

How do we double each item in a list without the use of any imports?

Some Example:

```
>>> multiply_items(['a', 'b'])
['a', 'a', 'b', b']
>>> multiply_items(['b', 'a'])
['b', 'b', 'a', a']
>>> multiply_items(['a', 'b', 'c'])
['a', 'a', 'b', b', 'c', c']
>>> multiply_items(['3', '4'])
['3', '3', '4', 4']
>>> multiply_items(['hi', 'bye'])
['hi', 'hi', 'bye', bye']
```

This is what I've come up with but it combines the elements together rather then in seperate string.

```
def multiply_items(sample_list):
    '''(list) -> list

    Given a list, returns the a new list where each element in the list is
    doubled.

    >>> multiply_items(['a', 'b'])
    ['a', 'a', 'b', b']
    >>> multiply_items(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ['a', 'a', 'b', b', 'c', c']
    >>> multiply_items(['3', '4'])
    ['3', '3', '4', 4']

    '''
    new_list = []
    for item in sample_list:
        new_list.append(item * 2)
    return new_list
```

Outputs I get:

```
>>> multiply_items(['3', '4'])
['33', '44']
>>> multiply_items(['hi', 'bye'])
['hihi', 'byebye']
```

Thank you for those who help :)

Comment: Here's a hint, you'll need two lines rather then one line in your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close... The **naive** approach:

```
for item in sample_list:
    for i in range(2):
        new_list.append(item)
```

Your problem was caused by the fact that strings are also lists thus `'a' * 2` is not `['a', 'a']` but `aa`. Now, knowing the problem, you can still solve it in a single loop by moving `item` inside a singleton list: the **better** approach:

```
for item in sample_list:
    new_list.extend([item] * 2)
```

Comment: It's probably optimized anyway, but is there really a need to use a nested for loop?

Comment: I was filling up the answer with more details and that as well ;)

Comment: Careful.  Your second code snippet should be `new_list.extend`, not `new_list.append`.

Answer (score 4):

I often prefer list comprehensions:

```
def multiply_items(l):
    return [i for t in zip(l,l) for i in t]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you view it as you're flattening a list where each element of that list is the elements repeated `n` times then you can write it as a nested list-comp:

```
data = ['a', 'b']
doubled = [item for sub in data for item in [sub] * 2]
```

The usual caveat applies that the "multiplied" items will be **the same object**... So be wary of elements containing mutable objects.

Comment: I can never get my nested list-comprehensions in the right order.  For some reason that syntax was never extremely intuitive to me.

Comment: @mgilson if it makes you feel better - I don't have to write them very often (I prefer chain.from_iterable) - and had to think about it, and had a couple of failed attempts

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly "clever" version which doesn't involve a nested list-comprehension<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [None] * (2*len(a))  # allocate new list
>>> b
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> b[::2] = a
>>> b
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None]
>>> b[1::2] = a
>>> b
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

To turn it into a function:

```
def multiply_list(lst):
    out = [None] * (2*len(lst))
    out[::2] = lst
    out[1::2] = lst
    return out
```

And then to generalize:

```
def multiply_list(lst, n=2):
    out = [None] * (n*len(lst))
    for i in range(n):
       out[i::n] = lst
    return out
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>I always tend to avoid nested list-comprehensions because I can never remember the order of those things...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
multiply_items = lambda lst: [item for item in lst for i in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that you can using the built-in `list` function.

```
def multiply_list(data, times):
    multiplied = []
    for item in data:
        multiplied=multiplied+list(item)*times
    return multiplied

print multiply_list(['a', 'b'], 2)
```